# GDAL MSSQL with numeric table names

Tags: gdal, sql-server

I have many SHP tables organised by year, for example 2015_xx_data.shp that I have loaded into a MS SQL Server database using OGR2OGR. I have also loaded them into MySQL for a comparison. There are no problems with the MySQL database but I am unable to get any features from the MSSQL database using OGRINFO.

I am using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.

I understand that the table names really should not start with a numeric and would need to be qualified with quotes or [] in this case. 
But the GDAL MSSQL driver does not seem to work quite right here.

**QRY 1**: If I use this syntax I get the Feature Count 0 and the correct SRS being reported, the fields being reported but no data is output:

```
ogrinfo -al "MSSQL:server=xxx\xxx;database=spatialtest;trusted_connection=yes;tables=dbo.2015_xx_data"

INFO: Open of `MSSQL:server=xxx\xxx;database=spatialtest;trusted_connection=yes;tables=dbo.2015_xx_data'
      using driver `MSSQLSpatial' successful.

Layer name: 2015_xx_data
Geometry: Line String
Feature Count: 0  <<<<<< !!!!
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS[...etc...]
FID Column = ogr_fid
isovalue: Real (6.2)
```

**QRY 2**: If I use this syntax I get Feature Count 3095 (correct) but the the SRS is (unknown) and no features are dumped because dbo.geometry_columns has "2015_xx_data" as the entry, not "[2015_xx_data]".

```
ogrinfo -al "MSSQL:server=xxx\xxx;database=spatialtest;trusted_connection=yes;tables=dbo.[2015_xx_data]"

ERROR 1: No column definitions found for table '[2015_xx_data]', layer not usable. <<<<<< !!!!
INFO: Open of `MSSQL:server=xxx\xxx;database=spatialtest;trusted_connection=yes;tables=dbo.[2015_xx_data]'
      using driver `MSSQLSpatial' successful.

Layer name: [2015_xx_data]
Geometry: Unknown (any) <<<<<< !!!! should be Line String
Feature Count: 3095
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
```

So I manually added a new row into geometry_columns with the f_table_name "[2015_xx_data]". QRY 2 now returns Feature Count 3095, the correct SRS but no data is output. ERROR 1 shows the problem.

```
ogrinfo -al "MSSQL:server=xxx\xxx;database=spatialtest;trusted_connection=yes;tables=dbo.[2015_xx_data]"

ERROR 1: No column definitions found for table '[2015_xx_data]', layer not usable. <<<<<< !!!!
INFO: Open of `MSSQL:server=xxx\xxxx;database=spatialtest;trusted_connection=yes;tables=dbo.[2015_xx_data]'
      using driver `MSSQLSpatial' successful.
Layer name: [2015_xx_data]
Geometry: Unknown (any) <<<<<< !!!! should be Line String
Feature Count: 3095
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS[...etc...]
No data is output <<<<<< !!!!*
```

I have tried many permutations on this, no luck. But MySQL works flawlessly.
I think the MSSQL driver isn't behaving as it should here, possibly a bug? 
Any advice on how to overcome this?

EXTRA INFORMATION

I have tried this with GDAL (ogrinfo.exe) 1.8, 1.11 and 2.0 - all same behaviour.

Quantum GIS Pisa 2.10.1 works fine and allows me to add the layers and they draw as expected. This means that QGIS or the GDAL library shipped with it is doing something different - not sure what.

Comment: While the latest SQL standard permits it, it remains best practice to avoid using numeric identifiers.